# Flask server runs, but Hello World does not display open in browser

Tags: python, flask

I ran the Hello World Flask program in Windows 10 with Python 3.6.4.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('127.0.0.1', 4996)
```

Error in the browser:

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 took too long to respond. Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Solutions I tried:

1. Changing the port number (multiple numbers) and the IP Address (to IPv4  address), but it does not reflect on the browser.
2. Installing python, Flask packages again.
3. Deactivating firewall
4. Resetting the proxy settings
5. Installed CORS plugin and tried running, also tried uninstalling CORS.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. You could also try `app.run('0.0.0.0', 80)` then try to access it with another browser on your network by going to the IP address of the machine running this code.

Comment: Hey! I did try in Firefox as well as Edge. Also, it didn't work for app.run('0.0.0.0', 80). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it by switching off the firewall protection in Quick Heal Security. Quick Heal firewall blocked my connection requests. 
Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually specifying the IP and port, let flask automatically set up the local server:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return "Hello World!"   

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.debug = True

app.run()
```

Comment: I tried that too! It didn't work. Any other suggestions?